# Unable to resolve "react-native-wheel-scroll-picker" from "App.js"

Tags: react-native

As per https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-scroll-picker

I did npm install react-native-wheel-scroll-picker --save

Then I copied the example into my App.js however...I get this error when I try to run it:

> Unable to resolve "react-native-wheel-scroll-picker" from "App.js"

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ScrollPicker from 'react-native-wheel-scroll-picker';

export default class SimpleExample extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
             <ScrollPicker
                  dataSource={[
                       'a',
                       'b',
                       'c',
                       'd',
                  ]}
                  selectedIndex={1}
                  renderItem={(data, index, isSelected) => {
                      //
                  }}
                  onValueChange={(data, selectedIndex) => {
                      //
                  }}
                  wrapperHeight={180}
                  wrapperWidth={150}
                  wrapperBackground={'#FFFFFF'}
                  itemHeight={60}
                  highlightColor={'#d8d8d8'}
                  highlightBorderWidth={2}
                  activeItemColor={'#222121'}
                  itemColor={'#B4B4B4'}
                />
        )
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
ok new error, first I added to packages.json with

> "react-native-wheel-scroll-picker": "0.2.4"

then I did the reset-cache, then i did npm start, then I get following error:
[image]

Comment: Three things: have you checked to make sure that `react-native-wheel-scroll-picker` is actually in your `package.json` and it's the version you expected? Second, have you checked that it's actually in `root/node_modules/react-native-wheel-scroll-picker`? Last, have you debugged your application to see what path it's resolving to? Maybe it doesn't match `root/node_modules/react-native-wheel-scroll-picker` because you have some webpack configuration that overrides all `^react-native*` packages or something, for example... there's a lot of things that could go wrong.

Comment: Will check. Thank you!!! I'm a 100% react noob, and this was the exact checklist I needed. Thx much. Very excited.

Comment: You'll get the hang of it after a while. I just started react-native a week ago and there's admittedly a lot of things you're expected to already know before you even start your project. If you haven't gotten past the "hello world" stage yet, I recommend checking out expo-cli. If I had known to try expo when I started, it would have saved me several hours of pain.

Comment: Also steer clear of `react-native-dom`... very buggy since it's brand new. Though since you seem to be doing android development, you're probably not going to be deploying to web anyway.

Comment: there might be a problem with the package itself, as (Snack) itself cant install the package

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. I figured it out, you have to install the npm package: styled-components.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components

You need this for the scroll wheel

https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor/issues/44

Comment: Hi RobPesc, welcome. Please consider adding more information because if the links become obsolete, this answer doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a case that you haven't restart the server and you try to use the package.

Just use below command to kill all the running server

```
killall node -9
```

And then start a new server

```
react-native start
```

I had the same issue when I tried to install the package and without restarting the server, I got the same error.

Comment: Sometimes `react-native start --reset-cache` may even be necessary

Comment: Correct as well

Comment: updated question at bottom with new errors and new attempts from me